# Can a single Action from the Action Editor hold multiple Transform animations?

Tags: animation, actions

I have a chimney and low poly cloud.
The cloud and chimney should have a shared animation in a single Action for later usage in Unity 3D and to make sure that the Animations play perfectly synchronously over numerous cycles.

But I only manage to animate a generic Object transform which affects both objects in the same way when I add them to the same action.

Here is a picture of what I am looking for. Is it possible like this?

[image: example of problem]

Comment: Actions are attached to objects, so as far as I know, you have to combine the cloud and chimney into a single action.  However, you can use the NLA to combine multiple actions, including those from different objects, into a single NLA track that will give you the synchronization -- although I don't know if you can export NLA tracks to Unity.

Comment: @MartyFouts can u "bake" multiple NLA tracks from different objects to one actions?